# How can I change the color and size of the text using elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[image]

How can I change the color and the size of this text using elementor!

I've tried to watch some tutorials on youtube but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Default Elementor element has style tab next to content, where you can edit font style and color, but in your screen shot it seems like its not default elementor widget, its custom widget of theme, so you should check theme option , it must be there, or you can write custom css.